# Why overflow does not work in this html code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I need a fixed table at the left then I would add dynamically tables at the right of the fixed table.

My html code is:

- Overflow-x: auto does not work

  ```
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Fixed Table</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Fixed Table</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>Some Content</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="containerForTables" style="overflow-x: auto">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <table class="table table-bordered" data-tablename="SOMEKEY">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">
                          SOMEKEY
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 1</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 2</th>
                      <th>SOMEKEY 3</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

It outputs:
[image: Fixed tables and tables added dynamically]

I expected something like this (look the horizontal scrollbar):

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [responsive grid sytem]http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Here is the code for 9 column responsive grid

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF NINE  */
.span_9_of_9 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_8_of_9 {
   width: 88.71%;
}

.span_7_of_9 {
   width: 77.42%;
}

.span_6_of_9 {
   width: 66.13%;
}

.span_5_of_9 {
   width: 54.84%;
}

.span_4_of_9 {
   width: 43.55%;
}

.span_3_of_9 {
   width: 32.26%;
}

.span_2_of_9 {
   width: 20.97%;
}

.span_1_of_9 {
   width: 9.688%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_9, .span_2_of_9, .span_3_of_9, .span_4_of_9, .span_5_of_9, .span_6_of_9, .span_7_of_9, .span_8_of_9, .span_9_of_9 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_9">
 1 of 9
 </div>
</div>
```

When you get your code you will have to change the span width to suit your needs for each column, like so.

```html
.span_1_of_12 {
 width: 22.6%;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 3.2%;
}
```